# Creating an online form - by Importing the questions from a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a spreadsheet where each row of the first column is a question, and the next 4 columns are the optional 4 answers to that question.

I want to turn these questions into an online form (like as the one offered by google docs)

Is there a web service that can offer something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Ragic](http://www.ragic.com) works for you. It's a spreadsheet style online form builder and fully supports creating a form from spreadsheet. You can also import more spreadsheet data to an existing form or export all / or filtered data to an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a Google form and create a "Grid" question.
2. In your spreadsheet copy the column of cells with your questions. (Don't copy the whole column.)
3. In the form's "Grid" question select the "Row 1" cell.
4. Paste in your cells. (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac)
5. Now go back to your spreadsheet and put your "answers" into a column.
6. Copy the column of cells with your answers. (Don't copy the whole column.)
7. In the form's "Grid" select the "Column 1".
8. Paste in your cells. (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) generates beautiful forms. They have a good [API](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/) and even a [CSV2Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/2010/03/10/import-your-data-with-csv2wufoo-com/) generator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PHP, something like [CSV parse](http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/) would be quite easy to implement and generate a form.